# How to clean and protect metal window frame from rust

Tags: rust-removal, rust

The metal arm from the window is rusted. What should I do? Metal brush and rust oleum paint? Some other product to clean the rust?

[image: window rust]

Comment: you have to clean it down to scheiny metal

Answer (score 1):

I usually wipe some vinegar on the rust spots and let it sit for 20 minutes but you've got cars below so you need to be careful what you put on it. A rotary tool, Dremel, with a grinding wheel or wire brush attachment works great. You have to go right down to the bare metal, not just to when the rust disappears. Rustoleum works good but again, don't spray it... remember the cars below..